# Part of plaintext is extracted and remaining HTML is displayed using JSoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I was trying to extract the pure plaintext from a html file but due to the non well formed of html or other, iam able to extract part of plaintext and remaining as html code only. How can we force the non well formed to wellformed html such that whole plaintext is extracted all the time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The code so far used is given below

```
File file = new File("pathofHTMLfile");
String parseHtml = FileUtils.readFileToString(file); 
parseHtml= parseHtml.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", " ");
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(parseHtml);
String st= doc.text();
```

The sample text file is given below int the following url
   https://github.com/snehareddy1990/test/blob/master/testnonwellformedhtml.txt

Comment: Can you place the file contents somewhere so we can have a go at debugging for you? And why are you doing a HTML unescape before parsing? My guess is that's the problem.

Comment: even after removing the html unescape still it is giving the same output. The input file is given in the url.